# Mover un objeto canvas con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy delimitando una zona con canvas en una foto de un producto, y de momento me sale bien, puedo mover la zona del canvas con los inputs, pero no se por que el horizontal no me funciona, no hace nada. Si se os ocurre una forma más fina soy todo ojos.

```js
$("#ancho").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var ancho = $("#ancho").val();     
    $("#c").css("width", ancho);     
});
$("#alto").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var alto = $("#alto").val();     
    $("#c").css("height", alto);     
});
$("#horizontal").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var horizontal = $("#horizontal").val();     
    $("#c").css("left", horizontal);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
canvas {
    border: 1px dashed rgb(195 195 195);
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    height: 150px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Ancho</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" value="150" id="ancho">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Alto</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" value="150" id="alto">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Horizontal</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" value="50" id="horizontal">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="center" style="text-align: center;>
   <span style="position: relative">
      <img src="https://www.sudeporte.com/13755-thickbox_default/sudadera-capucha-keya-100-negro.jpg" alt="" id="img_producto">
      <canvas id="c" style="width: 152px; height: 176px;"></canvas>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ademas de lo que te dijeron, te falto cerrar una comilla doble: `style="text-align: center;>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta poner la unidad de medida cuando agregas la propiedad left... si el valor es 50... son 50 que?
En este caso pongo 50 pixeles.

```js
$("#ancho").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var ancho = $("#ancho").val();     
    $("#c").css("width", ancho);     
});
$("#alto").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var alto = $("#alto").val();     
    $("#c").css("height", alto);     
});
$("#horizontal").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var horizontal = $("#horizontal").val();     
    console.log(horizontal);
    $("#c").css("left", horizontal+"px");     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
canvas {
    border: 1px dashed rgb(195 195 195);
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    height: 150px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Ancho</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" value="150" id="ancho">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Alto</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" value="150" id="alto">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Horizontal</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" value="50" id="horizontal">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="center" style="text-align: center;>
   <span style="position: relative">
      <img src="https://www.sudeporte.com/13755-thickbox_default/sudadera-capucha-keya-100-negro.jpg" alt="" id="img_producto">
      <canvas id="c" style="width: 152px; height: 176px;"></canvas>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pipe y una pregunta por que en el `width` o en el `height` no es necesario??? Y por que el `top` va con pasos tan pequeño y el horizontal lo hace bien?

Comment: La respuesta exacta no la sé... pero realmente lo más lógico es especificar las unidades de medida cuando se cambia algo del css. Quizas sea jquery que asigna por defecto "px" para cuando es width o height.

Comment: Nada olvida lo que dije, es por que no tenia zona de altura al ser un `span` lo cambie por un `div` y a funcionar. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cual `top`? solo veo width, height y horizontal?

Comment: SI por eso comentaba que no sabia como editar el código de la pregunta. Pero ya está arreglado